# Create a Link in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, menu

I'm trying to create a link in Drupal 7 with menu_link_save($link)

I'm checking the name of the menu with a var_dump which outputs:

```
array(8) { ["devel"]=> string(11) "Development" ["menu-drushcommands"]=> string(13) "DrushCommands" ["menu-footer-menu"]=> string(11) "Footer Menu" ["main-menu"]=> string(9) "Main menu" ["management"]=> string(10) "Management" ["navigation"]=> string(10) "Navigation" ["user-menu"]=> string(9) "User menu" ["menu-sub-menu"]=> string(7) "submenu" }
```

I've tried to add the link to the submenu using the key and also once using the value, but it doesn't work.

The only thing I can do is adding the menu item to the navigation bar which is the default fallback value.

this is my function:

```
function save_menu(){
$output =  menu_get_menus();
var_dump($output);  
    
$link = array();

$link['link_title'] = "menulinkname";      //required value
$link['link_path']  = 'ctModules/inserted nodename';    //required value
$link['menu_name']  = 'submenu';                         
menu_link_save($link);
menu_cache_clear_all();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing the line `$link['menu_name']  = 'submenu';`  with `$link['menu_name']  = 'menu-sub-menu';`  ?

Comment: There are a couple things that might be going wrong here. First, you should run your path through drupal_get_normal_path() to normalize it. Next, you should make sure that you are using the machine name of your menu, not just the name displayed in the admin interface. Finally, keep in mind that Drupal will not allow creation of a menu item that points to an internal path that doesn't exist. If there is nothing at www.website.com/ctModules/node-name, Drupal will not create the menu item.